# Windows Server 2003 Temporary Internet Files filling with hidden junk?

Tags: windows-server-2003, files

I have a server running Windows Server 2003.  Nobody uses the internet from this machine.  If I go to `C:\Documents and Settings\(user)\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files` and right-click for Properties, it tells me there is over 4GB in 24 files and 6 folders.  The only files shown are 2 cookies created in 2007.  I've set it to "Show hidden files and folders" and turned off "Hide protected operating system files".  My specific questions:

1. How do I see what's out there?
2. How do I find out where it's coming from? I don't think it's Explorer.
3. How do I periodically clean out the folder without doing it by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% certain about the first two questions, but there are lots of options for #3.  I personally use [CCleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com/) to scrub the cruft from the family PC automatically once a day.  If you run it by hand, it should give you list of files found, depending on the function you're using.

For #1 you could also try running "dir /s" while standing in that "Temporary Internet Files" from the command prompt.

For #2 it could be from any software that does automatic updates (such as Adobe Acrobat viewer, Sun's Java, and MS's own Security Essentials and Automatic Updates).  This is just a guess, as I'm not 100% certain where these apps store their downloads.

Comment: Thanks, `dir /s` is showing everything. The large files are created by a program I wrote that runs on the server - it will probably lead to another question on Stackoverflow.